# What does this set of vectors describe geometrically speaking?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

What does this set of vectors describe geometrically speaking?

$$\{(x,y,z):2x=-6y=4z\}$$

Comment: $\mathbf{r}=(1,-1/3,1/2)x$, so a line!

Answer (score 1):

Once you choose a value for $x,y$, or $z$, the other $2$ coordinates of the vector are determined so your vector space is $1$-dimensional.  $(-6,2,-3)$ is in the set so you have a line through the origin in the direction $(-6,2,-3)$.